# Add extra values to "next submission value"

Tags: webforms

Each time a webform is submitted it create a submission value i.e. 30 and when this is passed to the notification email it looks like:

http://localhost/sitename/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/submission/30

What I want it to do is to have the ability to create a unique/random ID to that URL i.e.

http://localhost/sitename/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/submission/30-abcd81091010

What I want to do is link the client to the submitted webform, but anyone could access any submitted webform just by changing the number in the URL.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: _anyone could access any submitted webform just by changing the number in the URL_ Only if they have permissions to view the submission with the second ID in the first place. And if they have permission, it’s fine for them to do that isn’t it?

Comment: Did you test your theory as non admin?